Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic: 24.04
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libcjson1 libpostproc57 libavcodec60 libavutil58 libswscale7 libswresample4
  libavformat60 libavfilter9
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 6.8.0-45.45); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                           Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-generic
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-image-generic:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-generic:amd64
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease      
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 6.8.0-45.45); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo apt-get clean
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 6.8.0-45.45); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo ln -s /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic': File exists
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo rm /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ sudo ln -s /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic': Operation not permitted
abhinav_sharma@Unknown:~$ 

I am tired of this please help I can't install flatpak without dealing with this.

See https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting for help on formatting your posts. Also, please [edit] and give us some context. What Ubuntu are you running? What are you trying to do? You have just given us a dump of command output with no context and no question, we can't help you with this.

Run sudo apt -f install followed by sudo apt full-upgrade and sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^

Based on the original error message "Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic: Operation not permitted", the output of findmnt -T /boot may be helpful

This question is similar to: Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I had an identical issue in my computer. As the apt was stalled, any update or new installation with apt/dpkg was doomed to failure. I even tried to reinstall kubuntu 24.04, but failed again when it was upgraded to 24.04.1.
Finally, I found a simple solution on this site (Issue with installing the latest linux image in lubuntu 20.04) that worked for me. You must just create a text file named /etc/kernel-img.conf (if it does not exist already) and type the following two lines:
do_symlinks = no
no_symlinks = yes

I hope it will work for you as well.

I am new to Linux based system so it will be helpful if you kindly provide me step by solution of above statement.

Open a text editor and copy the two lines above. Save it with the name you want (e.g., hello.txt) and run in terminal
sudo cp hello.txt /etc/kernel-img.conf
